# Network request failed error in real android device once Register using API

Tags: android, reactjs, android-studio, react-native

** I am trying to build a registration page in react-native which sends the data to an API. Whenever I try filling the form and sending the request, the emulator works fine but real android device shows a Network Request Failed error. I have read almost all related answers but none of them seem to help me. I am working with Android 7.0 API level 24. The code attached below.I have enabled internet permission in manifest file.**

```
fetchRegister(){
    var object = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body:JSON.stringify( {
        "phone_number": this.state.contactNumber,
        "password": this.state.password,
      })
  };


  fetch('https://example.com/chatapp/web/registrations.php',object)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseText) => {


        if(responseText.status == '200'){
              this.setState({
                registrationSuccessfull:true
              })

            var { navigate} = this.props.navigation;
            setTimeout(() => {
              navigate("Login",{screen: "Login"});
            }, 3000);
        }else if(responseText.status == '405'){
            this.setState({
              registeredAlready:true,
            });
        }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });
  }
```

Comment: where is the error screenshot?

Comment: I can't upload images because my account is new

Comment: `https://example.com/chatapp/web/registrations.php` is this the actual url you are using in your project, or are you testing on localhost?

Comment: @AswinPAshok example.com is that i added for security reasons. I host our all server files and give the URL of it. But still the same issue. Android Emulator with same specs works fine. Real device had this issue

Comment: try to access same page from mobile browser (Test device)

Comment: @AswinPAshok I tried. Can't access that page from mobile. But i can access from it by computer

Comment: So it's not the problem with your app. Something is wrong with server. I assume you are not locally hosting your api. If you are locally hosting (xampp, wamp,.. etc) you have to configure it properly

Comment: @AswinPAshok I tried localhost and it works fine. But the thing is with the URL of our API, android emulator works fine. This issue appears once i build the .apk file and install it on real device. Also it works fine once i connect real device to my computer and build via Terminal by the command "react-native run-android"

Comment: So you are connecting to localhost over wifi?

Comment: @AswinPAshok yes localhost working fine. Once i host all my API's error happens

Comment: You have to configure your local server to accept connection over wifi. It is disabled by default. So test device will not connect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little bit late to answer my own question but in this case, the mistake is how I get the debug apk from my project. Once I got debug apk it's not bundled correctly. That is the reason for getting network request failed error.

I found correct terminal code that we can get debug apk from react-native application.

```
mkdir -p android/app/src/main/assets && rm -rf android/app/build && react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res && cd android && ./gradlew assembleDebug
```